# How to mask a shape with multiple masks

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer

[image]

I want to mask a rectangle shape with two different shapes

Shape 1 Which is in shape of a circle

Shape 2 Which is in shape of rectangle

This is the code for setting stencil mask for shape 1

```
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 1, 1); // never pass stencil test
glStencilMask(1);
```

This is the code for setting stencil mask for shape 2

```
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 4, 4); // never pass stencil test
glStencilMask(4);
```

Now i can mask the geometry shape with a value of 5 and the shape will only be drawn where both the masks were drawn

```
 glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 5, 5);
 break;
```

But how do i draw the geometry where Shape 1 is GL_EQUAL and Shape 2 is GL_NOTEQUAL

Like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking where "Shape 2 is GL_NOTEQUAL", ask what value it will be **EQUAL** there. If you're interested in pixels that are in Shape 1 and **not** in Shape 2, then the value of the stencil buffer there will be `1`; that is `1` for Shape 1 plus `0` for Shape 2. You can do that test by modifying the `ref` argument to `glStencilFunc`:

```
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 5);
```

Comment: i have tried tried this but it does not work the way i want it to work , the circle should be drawn where we have mask 1 but if mask 2 two also happens to be overlapping on the same area as mask 1 than again the object should not be drawn in  that region.

Comment: @Summit: yes, that's exactly what it's doing. perhaps you should post the code that you tried but didn't work.